# Can using a SSD speed up "grep"?

Tags: ssd, grep

I need to use `grep` to parse a 50GB file, and it's very very slow on my server.

I wonder if it'll be faster if I replace my server disk with SSD? Is it worth the upgrade?

Thanks.

Edited:

This is what I got from `iostat`, how to see the I/O speed?

```
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
loop7             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop6             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop5             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop4             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop3             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop2             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop1             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
loop0             0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0
cciss!c0d0      652,87       399,77      3568,25  120296073 1073741823
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and if you want to grep REALLY fast you can make a huge RAMdisk. 
But you can also grep more efficiently:

1) If you're searching for a fixed string use 'fgrep' instead of 'grep'.

2) start your command like this unless it's a UTF8 file:

> LC_ALL=C fgrep 'somestring' hugefile.log

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913014/grepping-a-huge-file-80gb-any-way-to-speed-it-up

It's remarkable how much faster it is.

If that doesn't help and you have sufficient free threads try this:

Copy your file in a seperate directory so that's the only file in that folder and run this command in that directory:

> find . -type f -print0  | xargs -0 -P 4 grep
>   'somestring' > output.txt

The '-P 4' means it will start 4 processes. If you are truly IO limited this won't help but then you're sure an SSD will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using LC_ALL=C as well as fgrep :) It would still take me three days to finish the parsing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what performance do you see with "iostat" when your grep is running?

Comment: I added the iostat, how to tell the speed from this output?

Comment: Woops sorry, that's "iostat -m" to show rMB & wMB which are read and write spead in MB per seconds

Comment: ok I've done that